If The Son is The "Logos", meaning The Word/Voice of YHWH(God). Then didn't HE, The Son, really give HIS Name in Exodus 3:15?
Edit

"This question is similar to: Are the words that Jesus spoke the
Logos?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make
it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question
are not helpful for your problem."*

This isn't the same. The answer is inadequate with no "scriptural" basis, explanation for Exodus 3:15, and is based off of sheer conjecture.

Greetings and peace be with you. I hope this isn't too controversial, for all I care about is the truth. I was an atheist for over 20+ years who "converted" just 3 years ago. Not seeing "jesus" in the original Greek writings, and the nomina sacra being used in the Codex Sinaiticus and Vaticanus instead of "ΙΗΣΟΥΣ" led me to a deeper study. It goes from "IY"(Nomina Sacra), "ΙΗΣΟΥΣ/Ἰησοῦς", "Iesus", and then to "Jesus".
But what really matters is The Word itself. What does the Word say?
John 1:1

In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word
was God. He was with God in the beginning. Through Him all things were
made, and without Him nothing was made that has been made. 4 In Him was
life, and that life was the light of men.

"Word" is from the Greek word "Logos", that is normally translated as "Word", but can also be as "Speech". HE was Elohim(God) and with Elohim from the beginning. The Son was the first "born" over all creation, meaning HE was not "created".(Colossians 1:15) Through Him all things were made, and without Him nothing was made that has been made. HE was called "The Author of Life".(Acts 3:15) HE even calls HIMSELF "the Originator of God’s creation".(Revelation 3:14) Paul even says HE was, "Given The Name above all Names". We are told that YHWH is the Most High over all, for David said, "For You, O YHWH, are Most High over all the earth; You are exalted far above all gods."(Psalm 97:9), as just one example. HE is also "The Prophet" who was told to come as Israel's mediator just like Moses.(Deuteronomy 18:15-19, Acts 7:37)
We see that YHWH created the Heaven and Earth by HIS Voice... The "Logos", or the Hebrew equivalent "Dabar".
Psalm 148:5

Let them praise the name of YHWH, for He gave the command and they
were created.

Genesis 1:3

And Elohim(God) said, “Let there be light,” and there was light.

So according the the writings(scripture) The Son is the literal Voice of Elohim(God). Who was born, not created, meaning the first thing The Father did was speak. Then, everything made through that Voice(The Son).
The question is wouldn't that mean HE, The Son, told Moses HIS Name in Exodus 3:15? Can we now take John 5:43, and John 17:11-12 literal?
Exodus 3:15 - Literal Standard Version

And God says again to Moses, “Thus you say to the sons of Israel:
YHWH, God of your fathers, God of Abraham, God of Isaac, and God of
Jacob, has sent me to you; this [is] My Name for all time, and this
[is] My memorial, to generation [and] generation.

John 5:46

If you had believed Moses, you would believe Me, because he wrote
about Me.


A prevous question (well answered) posits the same kind of theory Are the words that Jesus spoke, the 'Logos' ?.

This question is similar to: Are the words that Jesus spoke the Logos?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Jesus is the visible manifestation of the invisible God the Father. Every time we read in the Old Testament about God appearing to somebody, by default it is preincarnate Jesus. In many places of the OT we come across the word of God (davar JHVH) coming to someone. It is not limited only to the sound one can hear. The word can be seen and touched (as in Genesis 15:1, Jeremiah 1:2-9 etc.). It has also a human-like form. In a nutshell the word of God is presented as a person. That interesting fact had been noticed by some of the ancient rabbis and biblical commentators. The observation was the basis of the Memra (word in Aramaic) theology. Their Aramaic commentaries to the different books of the OT are called Targums.

A targum (Imperial Aramaic:תרגום, interpretation, translation,
version; plural: targumim) was an originally spoken translation of the
Hebrew Bible (also called the Hebrew:תַּנַ״ךְ, romanized: Tana"kh)
that a professional translator (מְתוּרגְמָן mǝṯurgǝmān) would give in
the common language of the listeners when that was not Biblical
Hebrew. This had become necessary near the end of the first century
BCE, as the common language was Aramaic and Hebrew was used for little
more than schooling and worship. The translator frequently expanded
his translation with paraphrases, explanations and examples, so it
became a kind of sermon. Writing down the targum was initially
prohibited; nevertheless, some targumitic writings appeared as early
as the middle of the first century.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targum

We do know exactly, when the Memra tradition started, but in must have been before the beginning of the Common Era. It is also very likely, that the writings of Philo of Alexandria were inspired by the Targums translated into Greek.
This is how Targum Jerusalem interprets Exodus 3:14 and 6:3 (unfortunately big chunks of text are missing from that particular commentary):

And the Word of the Lord said to Mosheh, He who spake to the world,
Be, and it was; and who will speak to it, Be, and it will be. And he
said, Thus shalt thou speak to the sons of Israel, EHEYEH hath sent me
unto you.
https://www.sefaria.org/Targum_Jerusalem%2C_Exodus.3.14?lang=bi
And the Lord was revealed in His Word unto Abraham, to Izhak, and to
Jakob, as the God of Heaven; but the Name of the Word of the Lord was
not known to them.
https://www.sefaria.org/Targum_Jerusalem%2C_Exodus.6?lang=bi

After the ascension of Jesus, for over a century that followed, there were debates between the believing Jews seeing Jesus as a full manifestation of the Word of God (Memra/Logos) and unbelieving ones rejecting it. Eventually the whole concept was branded as heretical by the mainstream rabbinical Judaism in the second century A.D. Since it was too Christian like they got read of it almost completely. And, the memory of it was largely forgotten until recently.
In conclusion, yes, it was Jesus who spoke with Moses from the burning bush. Is YHVH the name of the Son or the Father? The answer is yes. As in Genesis 19:24:

Then the LORD rained down burning sulfur on Sodom and Gomorrah—from
the LORD out of the heavens.

I do recommend you check many lectures of Benjamin Sommer on fluidity of God (mind he is not a Christian but a practising Jew), and the late Michael Heiser presentations on the Two Powers in Heaven. There are many on YouTube.

Thank you for  your comment. "In conclusion, yes, it was Jesus who spoke with Moses from the burning bush. Is YHVH the name of the Son or the Father? The answer is yes."-- Then call HIM YHWH(YAHWEH), not "Jesus", that name is mistranslated. We are told in both Acts 2:21, and Romans 10:13 that the name to call upon for salvation is found in Joel 2:32: "And everyone who calls on the name of YHWH will be saved"

Jesus (Yeshua/Yehoshua) means YHVH saves in Hebrew. God bless.
